# How to unit testing a class that uses android.icu.text.* library with JUnit and Mockito in Android Studio? (in Java)

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, decimalformat

I am writing a class which handles formatting input text with given pattern.
I am using `android.icu.text.DecimalFormat` and `android.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols` (I used the `java.text.Decimalformat` before but it did not worked correctly on the real android device so I switch to use `android.icu.text.*` classes)
I am facing some issues:

At first It throws `Method ... is not mocked.` I fixed this one by add the testOptions in the `build.gradle` file. But then the DecimalFormat instance always returns `null`.

I tried every thing and It still does not accept my test case.
Please help me. Thank you very much

My class:

```
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.Locale;

public class NumberFormatter {
    public String format(String inputText, String pattern){
        DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbol = getDefaultDecimalFormatSymbols();
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = getDecimalFormat(pattern, decimalFormatSymbol);
        double value = Double.parseDouble(inputText);
        return decimalFormat.format(value);
    }

    @NonNull
    DecimalFormat getDecimalFormat(String pattern, DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbol) {
        return new DecimalFormat(pattern, decimalFormatSymbol);
    }

    @NonNull
    DecimalFormatSymbols getDefaultDecimalFormatSymbols() {
        DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
        decimalFormatSymbol.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        decimalFormatSymbol.setGroupingSeparator(',');
        return decimalFormatSymbol;
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class NumberFormatterTest {

    @Test
    public void format_givenInputStringAndPatternString_shouldReturnCorrespondingFormattedString(){
        String pattern = "#,###.##";
        String inputString = "1000.12";
        String expect = "1,000.12";
        String actual = new NumberFormatter().format(inputString, pattern);

        Assert.assertEquals(expect, actual);
    }
}
```

At first it showed this error

```
Method setDecimalSeparator in android.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setDecimalSeparator in android.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

After adding to gradle file like this:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

Then is always return NULL

```
expected:<1,000.12> but was:<null>
Expected :1,000.12
Actual   :null
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1,000.12> but was:<null>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146)
```

I tried to add `testOptions` in to `build.gradle`
I tried to mock the DecimalFormat object
I expected that it could return some object with my settings but it always return `null`

Comment: Use java classes not android classes.

Comment: I did. But the java classes did not work properly when it runs on real devices. That is why I switch to use android classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using android classes in your unit tests, [they are actually mocks](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/local-tests#mockable-library), not real objects. The error you're seeing [indicates](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/local-tests#error) that you're trying to access mocked android framework object, in your instance DecimalFormat.

You can either change android classes to java classes, as JakeB suggested or you can use some framework like [Robolectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) to make android framework partially work in unit tests.

Comment: I change my implementation to use the Java library(DecimalNumber...) as you and JakeB mentioned above with documents attached. The DecimalNumber from android lib behaves exactly as those that come from Java so I change them then I can test it with Junit as normal. Thank you.